# guidance on Mikrobus NFC tag and connecting to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, nfc

I've recently purchased an NFC tag reader from MikroE and ive been a little lost on connecting the reader to my arduino board.

I've also been looking online for a library that i could use for this device, and have found little to nothing, though i maybe looking in the wrong place. If you could provide any guidance to the matter please respond.

any help would be much appreciated.

link to the tag: https://www.mikroe.com/nfc-tag-click

Comment: There is link on the mikroe.com website to a PDF that describes your circuit board: https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/nfc-tag/nfc-tag-click-manual-v100.pdf  The PDF tells you to go to https://libstock.mikroe.com for code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find an Arduino library for a device, you can search for the term combination

```
Arduino github <devicename>
```

because most libraries are hosted on github. The devicename here means the chip on the product, not the product itself. You won't find much for "Mikrobus NFC", but when you search for the chip on it - the  M24SR64 - you can find some promising results.

For example [this library](https://github.com/rena2019/ArduinoM24SR), which looks good to me. It was used for [this blog article](https://regnerischernachmittag.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/m24sr-arduino-library/), which is where I found it (though that is a german site. I just wanted to link as reference for the german speakers). It has some examples, that show the usage of the library.

---

In general: Sometimes there might be no ready to use library for a chip or product to use with Arduino. In that case you need to write that code yourself. Let's take this product as example. It uses the I2C interface and the seller also links to the datasheet of the used chip. In the datasheet you can read, how the chip is used, including the communication protocol, that is imposes on the I2C interface. You could then write the corresponding I2C code using the `Wire` library.

Fortunate for you there already is a library, so you can first try that.